# lIndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is wrong with this code. I am trying to get input like this -
4 5 ||
3 6
and store 4, 3 in S and 5, 6 in E

```
N=int(input())
S=[]
E=[]
for i in range(0,N):
    (S[i], E[i])=map(int, input().split(' '))
```

Comment: Neither list has any elements, so trying to assign to any element is an error.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `s, e = map(…)`, then `S.append(s)` and `E.append(e)`?

Comment: Please refer to a tutorial on Python sequences (lists, tuples, etc.).  You have the basic syntax incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can not grow lists like this in python. If you want to add to a list, you have to use the following approach:

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(list_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, when you have a variable which is a list, it has a specific length, and if you try to access a member with a number greater or equal to that length, it will spit out the index error. Now to avoid this you could instantiate the array in one lane using the [] notion like so: (In this code the inputsSp variable is the inputs splitted into the corresponding members: for example inputsSp[i] = ['4', '5', '||', '3', '6'])

```
S = [[int(inp[i][0]), int(inp[3])] for inp in inputsSp]
E = [[int(inp[i][1]), int(inp[4])] for inp in inputsSp]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this via:

```
S, E = zip(*[map(int, input().split()) for _ in range(int(input()))])
```

or, the long version:

```
num_of_pairs = int(input())
full_input = []
for _ in range(num_of_pairs):
    full_input.append(map(int, input().split()))  # add each pair to the full input
S, E = zip(*full_input)  # the * is important as this unpacks the list for zip
```

This works by taking in all inputs and then [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ping the result, which sorts them as you wish. See it on [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/DirtyPalegreenSpecialist):

```
>? 2
>? 4 5
>? 3 6
>>> S
('4', '3')
>>> E
('5', '6')
```